# Confused by NBO output, due to missing bonds

Tags: computational-chemistry, transition-metals, orbitals

I'm about to do an NBO analysis to evaluate bond characteristics in a novel transition-metal complex.

As I have never done anything like that, I tried to understand the basic output for an octahedral ruthenium complex with three phosphines, two hydrides and a carbonyl ligand $[\ce{RuP_3(H)_2(CO)}]$ beforehand.
I'm expecting to find bonding orbitals for all three $\ce{Ru-P}$ bonds, the $\ce{Ru-C}$ and the two $\ce{Ru-H}$ bonds. However, the output only shows bonding orbitals for two $\ce{Ru-P}$  bonds and the $\ce{Ru-C}$  bond. The two hydrides appear as separate molecular units.

The missing $\ce{Ru-P}$ bond in the NBO analysis regards the phosphine in *trans* position to the carbonyl ligand.
I assume that due to the $\pi$-acceptor nature of the carbonyl ligand, "problems" in the NBO calculation occur leading to the absence of the *trans* $\ce{Ru-P}$ bond in the NBO analysis.

Can someone point me into the right direction to get my head wrapped around that? (Bonus: Why is NBO treating the hydrides as separate units and thus not finding bonding orbitals $\ce{Ru-H}$?)

Comment: I don't know if it would be too much text, but if possible could you include the relevant section of the output in your question? I don't know much about the NBO program, but it may help other users to see the output for themselves. Same goes for any unique input settings.

Comment: I'm not certain if the question is answerable without seeing at least a snippet of the output.

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. If someone would like to add an answer or the OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments, it can be reopened.